# How to create layout like android market app? Should I use tableLayout, GridView, or create custom one?

Tags: android, layout, google-play, listadapter

What's the best way to create android market like layout? I was thinking to use tableLayout, but then I need to handle rotation and re-layout. Or another option was to use GridView, but I cannot span more than one cell.

Can anyone point me to any good resource please? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this useful compatibility library for GridLayout: https://github.com/dlew/android-gridlayout and it supports Android version 1.5+

Answer (score 0):

i think the best way is to implement (extend) a framelayout. With this layout you
can position each child with leftMargin/topmargin layout attributes and can keep track
of each child's position and size, even if the device gets rotated.

btw: there is no layout prior android 4.0 that have col spans/row spans - with Android 4.0
you can implement that with GridLayout.

Comment: so are you saying that i wouldn't be able to do it in android pre 4.0? is this coverred in the compatibility package?

Comment: no, the android support v4 package have only some things like Fragments, the ViewPager and some Accessibility functions on board.

Comment: what do you think about GridLayout http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html

Comment: the GridLayout allows you to span cells/rows ... but its not possible prior Android 4.0

Comment: i see.. thank you. I am gonna accept this as answer for now. but if i am targeting Android 4.0 GridLayout seems easy to use.